# OSM printing in QGIS-Web-Client

Tags: print-composer, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

Printing in QGIS-Web-Client generates pdf with only QGIS project layers. I tried to add osm map in QGIS Composer but it doesn't work. It still prints only overlays. Is there any other way to print a map with osm baselayer?

Answer (score 2):

You can add OSM as a WMTS layer or with [GDAL](http://www.3liz.com/blog/rldhont/index.php?post/2012/07/17/OpenStreetMap-Tiles-in-QGIS) in your project and display it before you print the map.